# Best Upload for web application FTP or HTTP?

Tags: asp.net

We have a web application where the users from whole world would upload there file at a same time. We want an effecient, robust upload system. Max file size would be 50 MB.
There would be atleast 1lac users uploading at same time.
Please suggest which is the better upload system, FTP or HTTP? 
Currently we have http based upload where in we do get some errors like connection problem, session time out, time out error, etc...
Even suggest me for any 3rd party ftp upload tools if you come accross.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you're doing.

every user I ever met knew how to use a browser, but the standard random user doesn't even have an FTP client installed. So usually HTTP uploads aren't really problematic. I wouldn't wanna upload huge files, but 50megs isn't that bad yet. If you want an FTP upload you probably would go for a java applet, so your users are guaranteed to have even the software needed to upload their files. Any PHP/WebFTP things will just run you into the same problems again.

Sometimes if I don't know if things I want to do work well, its a good time to look at how others are doing it. Gmail for example has a fabulous upload system. imageshack, millions and millions of users are uploading their stuff their, basically thats all the page does, and all of them use "normal" HTTP, with a little bit of JavaScript sugar to display the progress.

edit: here is an example with PHP: (although u seem to be using asp, it might still help)
http://www.devpro.it/upload_progress/

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you yo go with HTTP, because it is much favorable in terms of user convenience.

If you are having critical issues with Large file upload then Please have a look at [Darren johnstone's Large File upload library for ASP.Net](http://darrenjohnstone.net/2008/07/15/aspnet-file-upload-module-version-2-beta-1/).

Still If you have to go with FTP then I will suggest you to go with using some Client Side reach technology which runs under browser like FLASH, JAVA Applets ( or might be SilverLight )